# How to change dateformat in vi editor

Tags: date, editor

I am new to vi editor. There are some `txt` files in database with date format like `01/01/2012` and I want to replace it with `dd.mm.yyyy`. Is it possible?

eg: 
01/01/2012 To 01.01.2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here be dragons.

```
:g:\d\{2}/\d\{2}/\d\{4}:s/\//\./g
```

Rough Explanation

`:g:<pattern>:<something>` -> globaly do `<something>` to a string which match `<pattern>`

So `\d\{2}/\d\{2}/\d\{4}` is the pattern. And you do `s/\//\./g` which means : Replace all occurences of `/` with `.` (the backward slash is just for escaping)

In case you are still confused, learn VIM regular expression
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace